# Session Time Out Priority. Time out described in which file has more priority? Global.asax or web.config file

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, session-timeout

I have a doubt regarding session time out.

In web.config file I am giving the session time out like below.

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="UseCookies" timeout ="30"/>
```

In Global.asax file i am specifying the session time out as below.

```
 Sub Session_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Session.Timeout = 10

End Sub
```

Which time out value will be preferred by the application? whether the web.config one or the Global.asax one?

Answer (score 0):

web.config holds the configuration data while global.asax holds the application start and end events, so you can see that definitely web.config has priority over global.asax.

We can also see this things like, you refresh your page after quite some time then application wouldn't go for Application_Start method to check Session timeout value, instead it will look for web.config.

I think you got my point now...

Comment: zeeshan, I tried a sample regarding the same as I have mentioned in the question. It is taking the global.asax timeout. Can you confirm it once? Even i had the same thought as yours but after trying the sample i became confused.